# How can i join Three tables and Create a table using Select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table in Mysql database `MIITEM`, `DEMAND`, `MIILOC` tables i want to select field from these three table display as a table .

i tried this but the join doesnt work for me

```
$sql = "SELECT demand.itemid, demand.qty, MIITEM.descr FROM demand
        INNER JOIN  MIITEM ON  MIITEM.itemId = demand.itemid
             WHERE demand.itemid =  MIITEM.itemId
             ORDER BY demand.itemid DESC";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["itemid"]. " - demand: " . $row["qty"].  " - sales: " . $row["sales"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: warp your select with new select and make join to the 3rd table...

Comment: @Proxytype you mean no JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

```
select dt.*, three_table.* from (
SELECT demand.itemid, demand.qty, MIITEM.descr FROM demand
        INNER JOIN  MIITEM ON  MIITEM.itemId = demand.itemid
             ORDER BY demand.itemid DESC) as dt inner join three_table on (dt.itemid = three_table.itemid)
```

you create the first select inner join 2 table wrap it with new select and inner join with the last table,

i didn't check the code... also you dont need the "where" you already doing inner join...

Comment: I get this message ` select dt.* from (SELECT demand.itemid, demand.qty, MIITEM.descr FROM demand INNER JOIN MIITEM ON MIITEM.itemId = demand.itemid WHERE demand.itemid = MIITEM.itemId0 results `

Comment: I used it like this `$sql = "select dt.*, three_table.* from (
SELECT demand.itemid, demand.qty, MIITEM.descr FROM demand
        INNER JOIN  MIITEM ON  MIITEM.itemId = demand.itemid
             WHERE demand.itemid =  MIITEM.itemId
             ORDER BY demand.itemid DESC) as dt inner join three_table on (dt.itemid = three_table.itemid)";`